# Wireshark UI, how to have current packet stand out in packet list pane?

Tags: wireshark

Default Wireshark UI seems to be very unfriendly in one aspect. When I'm scrolling and viewing a packet's detail, the UI gives very little visual clue about [which packet in the packet list I'm viewing]. Let me just call it "current packet" here.

Screenshot from Wireshark 4.0.1:

[image: Wireshare 4.0.1 UI]

Can you see which is the current packet?

I hope that there could be a dedicated column showing a red dot on the current packet, or something alike. Is there way?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, I don't think there's much you can do.  The only thing that comes to mind that you could do is disable all coloring rules (*View -> Colorize Packet List*) so that only the selected packet is highlighted.  Some people (not me) do prefer that style.  Other than that, you could open a new [Wireshark Issue](https://gitlab.com/wireshark/wireshark/-/issues) requesting such an enhancement be added to a future release of Wireshark.

By the way, if you're examining a particular packet, you can double-click it in the Packet List pane to open that packet in a new window; that *might* help you see the Frame number at the top, depending on how much of the packet details have been expanded.

Answer (score 0):

Using a Gradient-style strip on "inactive selected item" is much better now.

But it's still not optimal. Since the whole width gradient color obfuscates the underlying packet-grouping color, so I think it could be better if the gradient style applies to **No.** column only.

[image: Enable gradient strip]